# Getting error in file upload using karate api

Tags: karate

Could anyone please assist me to file upload functionality using Karate API? I have tried many ways, but getting error message as

```
"[{"title":"QUERY.BIZ.004","status":500,"detail":"Error in uploading document","timestamp":"2021-12-01T09:04:01.033+01:00"}]"
```

**PAYLOAD DETAILS**

```
metadata: {"key":"FILE_NAME","value":"karate-logo"}
metadata: {"key":"FILE_EXTENSION","value":"jpg"}
metadata: {"key":"TAG","value":"REQUEST"}
metadata: {"key":"DOC_TYP","value":"00008"}
file: (binary)
```

**REQUEST HEADERS**

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2368
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary9A1eYQihw4rdVq9f
```

Below mentioned karate API code which I used in the framework

```
Given url posturl
And path 'document'
And header id = '1608672'
And header Content-Type = 'multipart/form-data'
And multipart file file = { read: 'classpath:dataDrivenPayload/karate-logo.jpg', filename: 'karate-logo.jpg', contentType: 'image/jpg' }
And multipart field metadata = {"key":"FILE_NAME","value":"karate-logo"}, {"key":"FILE_EXTENSION","value":"jpg"}, {"key":"TAG","value":"REQUEST"}, {"key":"DOC_TYP","value":"00008"}
When method POST
Then status 200
```

Comment: please refer this and figure this out on your own: github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1645#issuecomment-862502881

Answer (score 0):

I think the `metadata` needs to be sent as multiple "parts".

Try something like this:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* multipart file metadata = { value: '{"key":"FILE_NAME","value":"karate-logo"}' }
* multipart file metadata = { value: '{"key":"FILE_EXTENSION","value":"jpg"}' }
* method post
* status 200
```

Otherwise, please use these instructions to troubleshoot, and work with your server-side team if possible: github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1645#issuecomment-862502881

Comment: Hi Peter Thomas, As you said, above code i tried. still getting same issue "[{"title":"QUERY.BIZ.004","status":500,"detail":"Error in uploading document","timestamp":"2021-12-01T09:04:01.033+01:00"}]"

Comment: @Ravi sorry, so file upload is REALLY tricky and if I can't get access to your actual API I can't help you. I've given you a resource, all the best: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1645#issuecomment-862502881